# Is the disk $D = D(z_0, r)$ a star shaped domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am very new to the concept of disks, but I thought that this particular one was just a circle centred at $z_0$ which is then obviously star shaped. But i was unsure as too whether this is to simplistic.

Comment: Any disk (or any non-empty convex set) is a star-shaped domain, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain. It *is* that simple.

Comment: If you want to be explicit, write down the straight segment between a point $z$ and $z_0$ and compute the distance to $z_0$ for all of these points.

Comment: Thank you! How would i go about determining whether $C^* = (z\in C: z\neq0)$ is a star shaped domain?

Comment: @Geoff: It isn't, because any star-shaped domain is *simply-connected*. But actually that is a different question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any disk $D(z_0, r)$ in $\Bbb C$ is a star-shaped domain: For any 
$z \in D(z_0, r)$, the straight line segment $[z_0, z]$ is contained in $D(z_0, r)$.

Slightly more general, any non-empty convex set is star-shaped (with
respect to *any* of its points).

The set $D = \{ z \in \Bbb C : z \ne 0 \} $ is *not* star-shaped:
For any $z_0 \in D$, the line segment from $z_0$ to $z = -z_0$
is not contained in $D$.

More generally, any star-shaped domain is *simply connected*, which
$D$ isn't.